# How do I change 3g/4g DNS on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, dns, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I want to change my dns permanently, preferably by using a init script.

Any ways this is what I’ve tried so far:

`setprop net.rmnet0.dns1 8.8.8.8` (outdated)

`ndc resolver setifdns rmnet0 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4` (This seems to be outdated aswell)

This seems to be the correct way of doing it:

`ndc resolver setnetdns <netID> <domains> <dns1> <dns2>`

But I don't know how to find the netID for rmnet0 and what to put in the domains part?

There might be a better way, like changing some files or applying a patch.

Answer (score 1):

The proper commands to execute depend on the Android version used. As I'm late with this answer, I assume you're no longer on 5.1.1 (or 6.0), where the answer would be

```
ndc resolver setnetdns <netId> <domains> <dns1> <dns2> ...
ndc resolver clearnetdns <netId>
ndc resolver flushnet <netId>
```

where `<netId>` would simply be `rmnet0`. A listing for most versions can be found [here](https://github.com/ukanth/afwall/wiki/DNS) in the AFWall Wiki.

Note that the first command alone won't stick until the next switch from WiFi to mobile data (I've tried that). Not sure if the two subsequent commands make it stick – I'm rather afraid that works like DHCP, so the on next connection the values are overwritten anyhow. If that's so, you'd need to run that script on every connection change (i.e. listen to that broadcast and run the script whenever a mobile connection got activated).